# Definition for rule 'import/no-extraneous-dependencies' was not found

Tags: reactjs, dependencies, eslint, typescript-eslint

I just added this eslint rule in my react.js project

```
"import/no-extraneous-dependencies": [
  "error",
  {
    "devDependencies": false,
    "optionalDependencies": false,
    "peerDependencies": false,
    "bundleDependencies": false,
    "packageDir": "./"
  }
]
```

After adding this rule I got an error on the first line of every file like this:

```
D:\MY_DAILY\Projects\React\src\components\Home\index.tsx
1:1  error  Definition for rule 'import/no-extraneous-dependencies' was not found  import/no- 
extraneous-dependencies
```

Same error is here [Definition for rule 'import/no-extraneous-dependencies' was not found #2019](https://github.com/import-js/eslint-plugin-import/issues/2019)

But I did not get any solution.